# Creating a range from datetime object in the column

Tags: python, datetime, time-series

```
df.columns
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-30', '2020-01-31', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-02',
               '2020-02-03', '2020-02-04', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-06',
               '2020-02-07', '2020-02-08',
               ...
               '2020-06-04', '2020-06-05', '2020-06-06', '2020-06-07',
               '2020-06-08', '2020-06-09', '2020-06-10', '2020-06-11',
               '2020-06-12', '2020-06-13'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=136, freq=None)
```

How can i create a range of start date and end date from the above columns.
I am trying to iterate over each date and access its values.

Answer (score 0):

you can used pandas date_range function

here is the documentation
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html

i have used like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((200,3)))
df['date'] = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=200, freq='D')
df = df.set_index(['date'])
print(df.loc['2000-6-1':'2000-6-10'])
```

Comment: Hi Pushpak, Thanks for the reply. Actually my columns are the dates in datetime format. I want to extract data from those columns and create a for loop where i will iterate from start date column to end date column. I hope you are able to understand my problem.

Comment: for i in range(start_date,end_date):
        d = data.loc[:,i]